# Random numbers - CGFloat

Tags: swift

Is there any idea or better approach do it more nice, elegant way ?

```
extension UIColor {
    static var randomColor: UIColor {
        .init(
            red: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0 ... 1.0)),
            green: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0 ... 1.0)),
            blue: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0 ... 1.0)),
            alpha: 1.0
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is more elegant but something I used in the past for a similar purpose: `let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0`

Comment: Thanks for answer but I dont think so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than …

```
CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0 ... 1.0))
```

… you can use:

```
CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
```

Or, in this context, you can let the compiler infer the type:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    static var randomColor: UIColor {
        .init(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1),
            alpha: 1
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Randomize color hue

If you want random red, green, and blue components for your random color, go with [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71777704/1045211)'s approach. If you want a randomly selected bright saturated color, randomize the [hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue).

```
extension UIColor {
    static var randomHue: UIColor {
        .init(hue: .random(in: 0...1),
              saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    static var randomRGB: UIColor {
        .init(red: .random(in: 0...1),
              green: .random(in: 0...1),
              blue: .random(in: 0...1),
              alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

[image]

It really depends what mean by "it" in the text describing what you want. Random components tend to yield dull colors.